# Yii2 acceptance test - Notice errors

Tags: selenium, testing, yii2, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to run acceptance test which has empty body:

```
class ContactCept
{
    public function frontpageWorks(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {

    }
}
```

This is my acceptance.suite.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://localhost/website/
            browser: chrome
        - Yii2:
            part: orm
            entryScript: index-test.php
            cleanup: false
```

My xampp is running and I can access http://localhost/website/

Selenium server is up and running.

When I run command vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance, my test is finished with error **Undefined index: HTTP_HOST**

PS: Chrome is opening with url data:;

My question is: **Can I disable errors of type "notice" and have only "error" level?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. In acceptance.yml add line:

```
error_level: "E_ERROR"
```